# Setting text color in custom sliding tab view on first display

Tags: android, tabs, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying so set the text color on sliding tabs within a custom view according to the tab state. It's working but not on initial display.

The textcolor in the custom view should be **white** when the tab is **selected** and **darker grey** otherwise. I got it partly working already: When I select a tab manually the text color changes correctly.

My problem is that on first display the text of the **first tab**, whose content is displayed initially and before any user interaction with the tabs, is **not colored in the active state color** (white). Its grey, like the inactive tabs. If I start interacting with the tabs, everything works, but the initial tab color of the first displayed tab is wrong.

```
[FIRST TAB | SECOND TAB]
     ^
    Grey (inactive color) on first load
```

**EDIT:**
The cause seems to be in the styles.xml: If I declare a custom style that inherits from *Widget.Design.TabLayout* the initial coloring does not work anymore. If I do not declare custom styles for the tablayout, everything works fine!

**EDIT2:**
No, it doesn't work. It works without setting the custom view but it still does not do the initial coloring correctly when first loading the tabs with setting the custom view.

Here is my code:

**tab_gallerylayout.xml** (custom tab view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.mbprojects.retro.view.RetroTextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/gallerytab_title_color"
    app:font="@string/font_name_syncopate"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**gallerytab_title_color.xml** (selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_grey" />
</selector>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>

</style>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution to this.  I'm having this EXACT same issue.  The "selected" state would appear to be incorrect when initially launched.  Clicking off the tab and back on to it works just fine.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I gave up since it took too much time. I accepted the default coloring while using a custom view. If you find a solution, please let me know ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this unusual behaviour is that your `viewPager` sets first item as current internally in `viewPager.setAdapter()`. This in turn makes tabLayout to select first tab in `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()`.

After this when you set custom tabs, state of custom view is not changed to "selected" (because select initial tab code already completed before this).

So, you need to explicilty change the state of custom view of selected tab.
Add below line after you set custom tabs and you're good to go.

```
mTabLayout.getTabAt(mInitialTab).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my setup has changed quite a lot in the meantime so I cannot test this anymore. I think I also tried that without success. Can anyone verify if this works?

Comment: I had the same problem and this works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:selector` in your xml instead of the `android:textColor`. The former is for dynamically changing an attribute while the latter is assigning one value and keeping it

Comment: There is no "selector" attribute in my case. The  custom RetroTextView inherits from TextView which does not seem to have this attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of something else then. Just a suggestion, why not make an imagebutton with an image that is supposed to look like your RetroTextView and apply the android:selector attr. to that instead?